Is it possible to translate/rotate the camera in geometry nodes?
I tried some obvious ways to control the camera in geometry nodes:

I created a geometry node group from an object and dragged the camera into the node group. Only when the camera node is set to 'instance' does it allow you to control the created instance but the camera view remain from the original camera's perspective. I also added the Active Camera node but it didn't change anything.


Then I tried to link the camera to an object so I can control the camera through the object. It worked when you translated or rotated the object in the view port but when you control the object with geometry nodes, the link between the object and camera is ignored.



How do you solve this problem?

As you can see in your second attempt, the object's origin does not move itself.
Instead of parenting at the object level, you can parent at the vertex level.
Select the camera, then select the object (the cube), enter edit mode and select three vertices of the cube.
Then make vertex parent CtrlP.
Now you can transform the geometry of the cube using transform geometry node and the camera will follow.
